# Changing FBLoginView size look awful with custom UIImage

Tags: ios, facebook, size

I've an image with the size 255x35 and I'm trying to change the size of the FBLoginView but the results are awful. 
I just want the FBLoginView to fit the image size.

My code:

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    loginView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 485, 255, 35);

    for (id obj in loginView.subviews)
    {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *loginButton =  obj;
            UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"login.png"];
            UIImage *loginImageHighlithed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"login_down.png"];

            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImageHighlithed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [loginButton sizeToFit];
        }
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            UILabel *loginLabel =  obj;
            loginLabel.text = @"";
            loginLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            loginLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    loginView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:loginView];
    [loginView sizeToFit];
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to create a **HiDPI resolution image (@2x)** for your "login.png" & "login_down.png".

Also, you need to **remove the [loginView sizeToFit]; method** to get rid of the view clipping.

Hope this helps!